# Creating a virtual directory failed with the error

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

I can't solve this problem

[image]

I suggest I have to change `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file and add after

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
```

the next line:

```
127.0.0.1       mysite.dev
```

but it doesn't help. Any suggestions?

Error ocсurrs when I try to open web site project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Check this: http://stonycreektechnologies.com/2011/03/15/iis-express-enable-remote-requests/

Comment: It is second or third google link, I got while searched solution in the Internet. It's not what I need.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I've already found the solution. I just had to edit `C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config` file, by adding my site to `<sites>` node.

Comment: In case this is not the answer for you and If you find yourself in my situation, I deleted the .vs directory to clear the cache and didn't notice that Visual Studio had changed my default build configuration to an auto-generated one that was configured to use IISExpress. So if you had a project that was working fine and then stops loading, I'd suggest before you do anything else to check the build config (which I of course failed to do)

Comment: Oops, while my previous 'helpful' comment was accurate it was not the root cause of the cryptic error message. That would be the fact that the automatically recreated .vs folder inherited NTFS encryption. Back to normal without needing to edit the project file after decrypting that folder.

Comment: Works even after 6 years. I got this issue with vs2017 latest version. But solved it using the above info.

Comment: When does one use local `applicaionhost.config` vs the one in the solution folder?

Comment: It didn't work for me.  Since I was not interested in running or modifying the project, just opening it to look at the code (indeed I don't even have IIS installed on my PC), I copied it from the network drive where it was located to a local drive and it let me open it.  I assume there is some trust setting that would get me there as well but could not figure out which one.

Comment: Renaming the IISExpress\config folder then re-opening the project worked for me.

Answer (score 206):

More often than not, at least in my case, this happens is when a `*.csproj.user` file is in the project directory and has `<UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>` in it.

> Alternatively, as mentioned by [Zachary Cutler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3225776/zachary-cutler) you can also simply: **close Visual Studio, delete the `*.csproj.user` file and reopen Visual Studio**. This will force VS to rebuild the file.

Comment: this not work for me , after update vs2017 15.7.1 ,I got this problem.

Comment: This didnt work for me. I have deleted `.vs` folder. deleted `*.csproj.user` and still gives the same error.

Comment: this also worked for me, I just deleted the [myproj].csproj.user file and it loaded - this was in VS2019 - running in admin mode

Comment: This was the answer for me. The disturbing thing is.. I already upvoted it. This answer is the gift that keeps on giving!

Comment: Visual studio 2022 'Creation of Virtual Directory Failed' was solved by this answer. unreal.

Answer (score 20):

You can opt to install IIS locally and edit a couple of tags on .csproj File.
Open you csproj file and go to section `<VisualStudio>` then find tag `<UseIIS>True</UseIIS>`
it must be set as true, then go to tag:  `<IISUrl>` and set up with the URL address where the application will be hosted for testing:

```
<VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>False</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort></DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          **<IISUrl>http://localhost/myWebSiteAppSample</IISUrl>**
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
```

And that is. Now you can load your project normally.

Comment: Funny, this is the answer for my case.

Comment: With a note: the `**` asterisks should not be in the file. Of course.

Answer (score 20):

The problem would be your project setup to be executed in the local IIS and the URL specified not exist.

There are options you can do to fix the problem.

**Option 1** : (Use IIS Express)

1.) Open you web project .csproj file as XAML or in notepad.

2.) Find these properties and set according to your preferences.

UseIIS = false

UseIISExpress = true

and that's it.

**Option 2** : (Use local IIS)

Follow the option 1 steps but change the following properties.

UseIIS = true

IISUrl = https://localhost

UseIISExpress = false

Comment: Option 1 not Working

Comment: Option 2 worked for me, just had to set UseIIS = true

Comment: Option 2 Worked :)

Comment: I just had to set UseIISExpress = false

Comment: Wow. Both options worked like a charm

Answer (score 11):

The issue can be fixed by deleting the folder named .vs in the project directory.

This solves the problem because while opening the project after deleting the .vs file, it creates the same folder with subfolder config and folder with project name.

The config folder **applicationhost** contains the necessary settings required to run the project successfully.

Answer (score 6):

I just went to the directory named in the error and renamed the applicationhost.config and restarted and VS created a new file and ran fine.

Answer (score 3):

- Tried several approaches mentioned in the answers, but what finally
  worked for me was swapping the `<IISUrl>` of `.csproj` with
  `<CustomServerUrl>`.

Edit :

- The above didn't solve the root cause of the issue for me. However,
  If you've done a windows update recently, perhaps it might be the
  reason that's causing the issue. Try executing `netsh http add iplisten 0.0.0.0` and see whether it solves the issue.

Hope these would help someone still looking for a way.

Comment: Of all the things (and I mean ALL), this (`<CustomServerUrl>`) is the one that finally did the trick for me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, by my `applicationhost.config` file was completely missing from my  `C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\IISExpress\config\` folder.

Copy/pasting `C:\inetpub\history\applicationhost.config` into that folder seemed to fix the problem for me.

Got the idea [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25429425/183624).

Comment: In my case file got corrupted. so I deleted it and replaced it with a applicationhost.config file found on system search. I don't have admin right so can't access inetpub\history. I think Visual studio always  expects this config file but after that even though I deleted the applicationhost.config  file repeatedly from  IISExpress\config location VS kept on creating it. Looks like sometime settings gets corrupted but once it is inline with right settings VS takes care of all settings of its own.

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn on windows features "Internet Information Services" in control panel.
2. Open ".csproj" file and find
3. Modify this line based on your requirements.
   http://localhost:777/
4. Open the project/solution now
5. If failed to load again, just right click the solution and select "Reload Project".

Answer (score 1):

I know this is probably a rare occurrence, but figured I'd put it here:

My `csproj` file was set to "read only" (Don't ask me how I managed that), but after I turned off "read only" access, everything was fine. (VS2017)

Answer (score 1):

Not the exact same error, but I was lead to this answer since the first half of the error matched. Your applicationhost.config file may simply be read-only. Taking that off solved the error for me. That error calls out the file specifically though, so you should be able to find it easily.

Answer (score 1):

I had to somewhat combine some of the above answers.  My solution was to edit (not delete) the file `.vs\config\applicationhost.config`

There is a section for the bindings of the site, simply change from localhost to whatever you desire to run it under.  Note that the port numbers are in front of the server name.

[image: applicationhost.config bindings section]

Comment: Thanks a million - this solved my problem, too!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by editing the file *.csproj in the root level of the project.   I changed  and  from localhost to the site name as shown below.  It may also be required to have the OverrideIISAppRootUrl set to True.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue because of my network password changed.I changed my NetExtendor login password but I have to login in my laptop with old password.

Try these steps to fix this issue:

log into the Computer with whatever password works
log into vpn with whatever password works
ctl-alt-del to lock the pc then use the new password to unlock it

It worked for me :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My issue was with Windows 10 Defender. I had given IIS permission in the past, but seems like it is now ignoring it. Will look into it later, but for now I disabled controlled folder access and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted open an exiting project of Visual Studio 2017 in VS 2019 and encountered with the same issue. I find its a version related problem. The solution is: Create a new project in the newer VS and copy the codes from the older VS.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In the question, there is no mention to any change on VS version. When you post an answer check that you are replying the question. If not, then just create a question with this issue and answer yourself, so it will help the Community.

Answer (score 0):

Try decrypting the applicationhost.config file. That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> Creation of the virtual directory xxxx failed with error: Object
> reference not set to an instance of an instance of an object...

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OjYx.png)
This issue happened to me after deleting my local repository and downloading the repository from the cloud.

Per one of the solutions above, I deleted the .vs folder with no luck. To solve the issue, I ended up mixing a couple of the solutions in this forum.

I went to the folder *.vs/SolutionName/config* and pasted the *applicationHost.config* file from the latest subfolder on the folder *C:/inetpub/history/*

After that, I restarted VS and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

simply fix for me 
Close your Visual Studio

o remove .vs in .Net
o remove IISExpress in Documents

Reopen it, everything should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@saminpa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2392316/saminpa), I found [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170133/creating-a-virtual-directory-failed-with-the-error#comment91229922_12177802) helpful in my situation, so, I added it as an answer to be found easily.

If the `.vs` folder is encrypted by the NTFS encryption system (EFS), this error will be seen.

Answer (score -1):

So here are the steps to fix it:

1. Go where your .csproj file is. This is usually one directory below the solution (.sln)
2. Right click and open with a text editor (notepad)
3. Find IISUrl tag and replace its content for http://localhost:(YourPortNumber)
4. Save and reload your project!