# The IIS Express applicationHost.config file contains invalid entries and must be corrected before you can open project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, iis-express-10

I have installed Visual studio developer community version to practice coding. When I tried to create a new web project, I am facing issue like configuring IIS express failed, can not read the configuration file. I have tried all possible solutions like renaming the host file and closing and opening the visual studio. Nothing worked out. And I have tried to clone the project from git here also I am facing the same issue. Can someone please help me here.

Here is my error message.

[image]

Comment: try the solutions mentioned in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25429425/3377344).

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24582929/unable-to-create-a-new-web-project-in-visual-studio-2013

Answer (score 76):

1. Go: **C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\config\templates\PersonalWebServer**
2. Copy 3 files: **applicationhost.config, aspnet.config và redirection.config**
3. Go to:  **Documents\IISExpress\config**
4. Paste and replace all 3 files
5. Reload

Comment: Don't know what's the cause of error, but it did solve it :D

Comment: Onedrive had synced my `Documents\IISExpress\config` files from another computer which could have been the culprit.

Comment: Had same issue, but just because I have 2 versions of visual studio installed.

Comment: On a 64-bit setup, you may need to get the files from C:\Program Files instead of C:\Program Files (x86).

Comment: I found that the files are not there, just one drive equivalent of these files

Comment: You sir are the people's champion. I'm wondering if installing build tools causes this somehow. I'm working with a fresh machine so this is quite odd.

Comment: This works, in my case because OneDrive replaced my new files

Answer (score 7):

Here is another suggestion which seems a bit easier.

1. Navigate to C:\Users\{{your user name}}\Documents\
2. Rename the folder IISExpress to IISExpressold or something so that its archived
3. Open your solution again.

It should open ok after these steps.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem with help of Drave answer. But I put that 3 files into below address:

```
[my project]\.vs\config\
```

when I put that files into confing folder and I reloaded the project, problem solved.

tnx again from Drave answer

Answer (score 2):

In my case with VS2019 works:

1. close VS2019
2. remove [my project].vs\config\
3. rename c:\Users[username]\OneDrive\Documents\IISExpress\config to _config
4. rename c:\Users[username]\Documents\IISExpress\config\ to _config
5. load the solution to VS2019

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the OneDrive application is removing by default the content of "C:\Users\username\Documents\IISExpress\config" folder, so Visual Studio cannot copy the .config files into .vs folder on the solution directory.

I resolved it by ensuring the files are on this path, and disabled the backup option on Documents directory in the OneDrive settings.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @silas my issue was with OneDrive as well. after disabling OneDrive sync on "Documents Folder" problem gets resolved. To be precise
system was trying to access
"C:\Users[user name]\Documents\IISExpress\config"